# MongoDb update leading zero for all records

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB collection that contains users.
Every user has a phone number (saved as a string).

Some phone numbers start with a 0 and some don't.

I need all phone numbers to start with a zero.

What will be the best way to update all records in the collection and add a leading zero only to the phone numbers that don't start with 0?

Thanks

Comment: you could convert to string and check the start digit, or use regex ^0

Comment: How do i do it in a query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
db.coll.update(
{     phone:{ $not:/^0/ } }, 
[
    {
        "$addFields" : {
            "phone" : {
                "$concat" : [
                    "0",
                    "$phone"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

- filter phones not starting with **0**
- Adds 0